# Find the count of categories from a table

Tags: mysql, group-by, count, right-join

I am trying to develop an enquiry management system for an institute.
I have 3 tables in mysql db.

1. `leads_course_category` table keeps course categories and has the columns: `category_id`, `category_name`, `category_created_time`, `category_deleted`.
2. `leads_course_details` table stores courses under categories and has the columns: `course_id`, `course_category_id`, `course_name`.
3. `leads_enquiry_details` table stores enquiry details and has the columns: `enquiry_id`, `enquiry_name`, `leads_course_details_course_id`, `enquiry_deleted`

I need to find the number of enquiries for each category.
I tried the following query:

```
SELECT category_name,COUNT(*) as COUNT
FROM leads_course_category
RIGHT JOIN   leads_course_details 
on category_id=leads_course_details.course_category_id  
RIGHT JOIN `leads_enquiry_details`   
on leads_course_details.course_id= leads_enquiry_details.leads_course_details_course_id  
WHERE leads_enquiry_details.enquiry_deleted=1 
GROUP BY leads_course_category.category_id
```

This query skips all the categories having null values, but I need to show that as count of zero.

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Right joins are almost never used - it's not incorrect to use them but in most cases left joins are much more understandable.

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info on how to improve your question.  If you can provide a schema to replicate the problem it is easier for others to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition `enquiry_deleted = 1` must be moved to the `ON` clause:

```
select c.category_name, count(ed.enquiry_id) count 
from leads_course_category c 
left join leads_course_details cd on c.category_id = cd.course_category_id  
left join leads_enquiry_details ed on cd.course_id = ed.leads_course_details_course_id and ed.enquiry_deleted = 1 
group by c.category_id, c.category_name
```